# AKS - creating clusters is broken?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

When I go to the "Networking" page of an existing AKS cluster, I get an error:

```
Extension: Microsoft_Azure_ContainerService
Content: ManagedClustersNetworkingBlade
Error reason: ErrorLoadingExtensionAndDefinition

Error: Failed to retrieve the blade definition for 'ManagedClustersNetworkingBlade' from the server.
 self.importscripts failed for "ExtensionCore/Arm/RegisterProvider"
```

A similar error occurs if I try to click the "Create" button to make a new AKS cluster in Azure. Is it broken for everyone, or is it a specific issue I'm having? I'm just wanting to confirm that somebody out there, right now, could create a brand new AKS cluster if they wanted to.

Comment: Works on my machine (all default settings except monitoring set to off)

Comment: Thanks, that's the main thing I was trying to figure out. I'll just take the rest up with the Azure support team.

Answer (score 1):

CSharpRocks confirmed above in the comments that it's not an Azure issue happening globally.

**Update May 2022**:
Azure support eventually worked this out with me. A workaround we discovered in the process was to try from a different browser. So I used Chrome instead of Safari, for example. Also, clearing my browser state (cache) eventually got my account working again in the original browser after they pushed some updates.